Export from Apple Books on iPhone to desktop without a cable
I have a iPhone 15 Pro running iOS 18.1.1. I have 15 no-DRM eBooks I want to export from my phone, but with one problem: I can't use a cable.
I also have an MacBook Pro 2019 running macOS 15.1.1.
How can I get these books out of my iPhone and onto my Mac?

I finally was able to get my books off my iPhone (with the port cleaned) using iMazing and a cable.

That’s a solid product - good value, excellent features.
